# Teradata BTEQ - Invalid timestamp issue

Tags: teradata

I am trying to execute an sql through TERADATA BTEQ and getting the below error.

But the same sql is running good when getting executed in Teradata SQL assistant.

```
WHERE S_ORDER_ITEM.LAST_UPD  BETWEEN CAST( (('20050614' (DATE, FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')) -1 (CHAR(10)) )|| ' ' || '22:00:01' AS TIMESTAMP(0))  AND CAST( (('20050614' (DATE, FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')) (CHAR(10)) )|| ' ' || '22:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP(0) )
 *** Failure 2666 Invalid date supplied for S_ORDER_ITEM.LAST_UPD.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that `S_ORDER_ITEM.LAST_UPD` is not a date/timestamp (char?) and the automatic typecast to a timestamp fails due to bad data.

This part `'20050614' (DATE, FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')` should never work, because the string doesn't match the Format.

There's no need for casting a string to a date, because the recommended way to write a date literal is simpler and shorter, using Standard SQL `DATE '2005-06-14'`.

If the date is actually known you better write

```
BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2005-06-13 22:00:01'
    AND TIMESTAMP '2005-06-14 22:00:00'
```

Otherwise don't cast to/from string, use datetime calculations instead:

```
BETWEEN Cast(DATE '2005-06-14' AS TIMESTAMP(0)) - INTERVAL '01:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND
    AND Cast(DATE '2005-06-14' AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + INTERVAL '22:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND
```

Edit:

If you can't change the input format you need to apply another FORMAT:

```
BETWEEN Cast((('20050614' (DATE, Format 'YYYYMMDD')) -1 (Format 'yyyy-mm-dd')) || ' ' || '22:00:01' AS TIMESTAMP(0))
    AND Cast((('20050614' (DATE, Format 'YYYYMMDD'))    (Format 'yyyy-mm-dd')) || ' ' || '22:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP(0))
```

Comment: S_ORDER_ITEM.LAST_UPD is TIMESTAMP(0) data type and my input date is in format YYYYMMDD (no hypens). Could you please modify the answer

Comment: I have converted my date format from YYYYMMDD format to YYYY-MM-DD format and then applied your solution. It worked.

Answer (score -2):

timestemp error occurs when your phone time is wrong
The solution is to correct your device time